# Model Compression why it works very well? Explanation please

Tags: machine-learning, compression, supervised-learning

Model compression: Let me explain this in simple terms.

Lets X_train (features), Y_train (target) be the training data.

```
X_train, Y_train ------> M1 (Example: decision tree)

X_train --------> M1 ----> Y_pred (predicted Y for X_train)
```

Now

```
Case 1:
    X_train, Y_pred -----------> M2 (Example: any model that is NOT decision tree)

    X_train ---------------> M2  ----------> Y_pred1 

Case 2:
    X_train, Y_train -----------> M2 (Example: any model that is NOT decision tree)

    X_train ---------------> M2  ----------> Y_pred2
```

Now I compute AUC score for M2.

```
Case 1:
 AUC (Y_pred, Y_pred1)
Case 2:
  AUC (Y_train, Y_pred2)
```

Case 1 AUC is higher than Case 2 AUC. Case 1 is called model compression. I like to get the intuition behind it. Of course AUC is calculated with probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition behind the result is that the conditional entropy of `Y_pred` given `X_train` is zero. So M2 can learn `X_train-> Y_pred` more easily than in second case.